# How to determine a spectral decomposition of the self-adjoint operator $D=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let’s say I have an operator:
$$D= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$$ on a Hilbert space $$H=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: f(0)=f(1)=0, ||f||<\infty\},$$
where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the corresponding inner product on $H$.

I try to determine a spectral decomposition of $D$ but don’t know how to do that. I do only know that there exists a spectral decomposition.

Thanks!

Comment: Write down the eigenvalue equation for $D$. It's a differential equation of some kind; does it look like one you can solve?

Comment: I guess you mean a differential equation, right? Would one choose an arbitrary orthonomal system on $H$ in order to solve this equation?

Comment: You have not specified the types of functions you are using, or the inner product, which means you can't discuss the operator being self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the Hilbert space is $H=L^2[0,1]$, and assume that $D$ is defined on the subspace $\mathcal{D}(D)$ consisting of every $f\in H$ that is equal a.e. to a twice absolutely continuous function $\tilde{f}$ such that $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{f}(1)=0$, and, of course, assume further that $D\tilde{f}=\tilde{f}^{''}\in L^2[0,1]$. Then $D$ is a closed, densely-defined linear operator:
$$
            D : \mathcal{D}\subset L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1].
$$
This operator is self-adjoint, and it has a complete orthogonal basis $\{ s_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $L^2[0,1]$ that consists of eigenvectors of $D$:
$$
       Ds_n=-n^2s_n,\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The spectral decomposition of $D$ is
$$
          Df=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-n^2\frac{\langle f,s_n\rangle}{\langle s_n,s_n\rangle}s_n,\;\; f\in\mathcal{D}(D).
$$